# What is the method to do that?

Tags: c++

Hello if i have a code like this  the user should input the locations  of exams

```
# include <iostream> 

Using namespace std ;

Int main ()

{

  string Halls [100] ;

for (int  i=0;i <99;i++)
{

Cin >> Halls [i];

} 

Return 0; 
}
```

SO  if there is repeated halls in them and I want to output the number of halls but  the repeated   halls  are not taking into consideration   for example ( hall 1 ; hall 2 , hall 2 ) so I have number of hallstudents 2 not 3 . How can I do that? 
 Will what I tried to do is to try to put  the first element in the halls array in  another array  then when trying to put another element in the second array I will try to do condition to ask if the second element is  the same as the first if it is I won't put  if not I will , but I do not know how I will do that ?  Any help please ?

Comment: I would probably start from here : http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c++-tutorial.html or any other simple tutorial to C++.

Comment: @Noname Using the right collection usually avoids a lot of problems. In this case a set (ordered or not) would probably be better.

Answer (score 2):

One hint: Read to a temporary string variable, and store the values in `std::set<std::string>` - there you can check if the value has been already entered before.